# How to merge two repositories from GitHub and GitLab?

Tags: git, gitlab

I have two version control systems. One is on GitLab at my local institute. The other one goes public, on GitHub. So I have two repositories for my project:

On GitLab, I have a history of commits like this:

```
commit c:
commit b:
commit a:
```

On GitHub, I have a history of commits like this:

```
commit f:
commit e:
commit d:
```

I know that `a` and `d` are the same version I pushed to both GitHub and GitLab. Now I have someone developed new features on GitHub with commit `f` and `e`. And I also have developed new things on GitLab with commit `b` and `c`. How to merge the commit `f` and commit `c` on both GitLab and GitHub? Is there a way to merge all the record of commits to get something like this:

On GitLab:

```
commit g: the merged version of c and f'
commit f': the same version as commit f on GitHub
commit e': the same version as commit e on GitHub
commit c:
commit b:
commit a:
```

On GitHub

```
commit h: the merged version of c' and f
commit c': the same version as commit c on GitLab
commit b': the same version as commit b on GitLab
commit f:
commit e:
commit d:
```

And now `h` and `g` are the same again.

Comment: You merge two branches like you always merge two branches. It doesn't matter if the remotes are hosted at GitHub or gitlab or anywhere else.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Sorry, my mistake. For historical reasons, these are not one repository with two branches, but two separated repositories. But I do know that commit `a` and `d` are the same. Does it make sense to you?